# Plot bargraph - pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pyspark, graph

I have a pyspark dataframe named df16 looks like below and i have to generate bar graph out of it.

In 1997 the count of brand Chevrolet is 1 as shown in the image, similarly for subsequent years the count would be increased.I have to show the increase in particular brand say 'chevrolet' for each year in bar graph.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpvDY.png)

However, i tried the below code, it didnt work out.Err: DataFrame constructor not properly called!.
Kindly help .

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(df16)

df.plot('Brand', 'Model Year',kind='bar', legend=False)

plt.ylabel('count')

plt.title('vehicle count')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line here:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(df16)
```

You should instead use this spark method to convert your spark DataFrame into a pandas DataFrame: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas.html

```py
df = df16.toPandas()
```